# Esconder menu, mostrar sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Estou fazendo um site em wordpress, mas o meu problema é que, eu quero esconder o menu por defeito e fazer com que apareça só o sticky menu.

Como posso fazer isso com javascript?
Já tentei e pesquisei, mas nunca consigo chegar ao resultado pretendido, não consigo esconder o menu original e mostrar só o sticky.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function($) {
  if (jquery('#mysticky-nav').hasClass('up')) {
    jQuery('#mysticky-nav').css("opacity", "0");
  } else {
    jQuery('#mysticky-nav').css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem, você quer exibir/esconder o menu no momento do carregamento da página ou quando rolar a tela? Pois se for no carregamento, poderia ser algo assim:

```
window.onload = function escondeMenu() { 

     let menu = document.querySelector('#IdDoMenu'); // INSIRA AQUI O #id ou .class DO MENU QUE VOCÊ QUER ESCONDER NO LUGAR DO PARÂMETRO PASSADO NO 'querySelector'
     let sticky = document.querySelector('#mysticky-nav');

     menu.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;');
     sticky.setAttribute('style', 'display: block !important;');
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.